# Azure resource Health Alert - not triggered

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse, azure-alerts, sql-azure-alerts

I have set up resource health alerts for my Azure SQL database and recently I saw there was a service unavailability but resource health alert didn't get trigger.

I have my alert conditions as following :-
[image]

where previous resource status is [unavailable, Unknown] .

Below is where I could fine that my resource health tab showed the unavailable status on the mentioned date.

[image]

I want to understand the possible reasons why my alert might not have been triggered. Is it related to previous resource status?

Also Azure is recommending me to create alerts whereas I have already configured an alert for the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for this bus one of the common reasons is they **may be action suppressed by an alert suppression rule**.

Look for suppressed action groups in the history tab and by clicking on the fired alert in the portal. If it was an accident, you can change, turn off, or get rid of the alert processing rule.

If an associated alert processing rule did not function as intended despite the fact that you may see a fired alert in the portal, check below things

- alert processing rule enabled
- if action is suppressed by alert processing rule

Refer - [Troubleshooting problems in Azure Monitor alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-troubleshoot)